# Do AirPods charge batteries with Qi now?

Tags: airpods, charging

The [Apple page](https://www.apple.com/iphone-x/#wireless-charging) about "Wireless Charging" talks about Apple's new *AirPower* mat due in 2018 working with iPhone, Apple Watch, and AirPods. Elsewhere it talks about standard [Qi charging technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(standard)) being used.

Does that mean today’s AirPods charge with any Qi-compliant charging pad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, but...**

Current AirPods can only be charged with a Qi-compliant charging pad if they're in the appropriate case. By *appropriate case* I mean Apple has launched a new optional charging case that supports wireless charging for AirPods.

**[EDIT]**

You may wish to read:

- [Apple announces a wireless charging case for the AirPods](https://techcrunch.com/2017/09/12/apple-announces-a-wireless-charging-case-for-the-airpods/)
- [Apple Intros AirPower Charging Mat, Wireless Charging AirPods Case](https://www.macobserver.com/news/product-news/apple-airpower-wireless-charging/)

> Apple revealed a new AirPods case that works with Apple's new AirPower charging pad. To charge the new wireless case, you place it
>   on the AirPower. If your AirPods are in the case, you’ll see an orange
>   light if they’re charging, or a green light when they’re nearly fully
>   charged. If no AirPods are in the case, the light still goes on when
>   you open the lid, but it indicates how much battery life is left in
>   the case itself: orange for needs charging and green for good life
>   left.
>
> As of this writing, Apple has not released pricing for the new
>   wireless case, nor has the company said that it will replace the
>   original case with the new one with a new pair of AirPods. The
>   wireless case will be available in 2018.

**Source:** See second link above

Comment: ??? What does "appropriate case" mean? You mean some third-party product that envelopes the AirPods case?

Comment: Can you cite some source for this info?

Comment: It was mentioned in their event, although it wasn't highlighted in any way. I will see if I can find something in writing and add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## No

No, today's AirPods do *not* work with Qi charging technology.

You have to read the fine print. Click the [itty-bitty tiny `6` footnote link](https://www.apple.com/iphone-x/#footnote-6). Read the text in tiny font (emphasis mine):

> Sold separately. Requires compatible iPhone, Apple Watch, or AirPods. **AirPods with wireless charging capabilities coming in 2018**.